# Unwanted Links and Spam Wordpress Pages and Posts

Tags: plugins, permalinks, urls, security, spam

In webmaster tools I have a number of crawling errors of the Google spider. for example

http://mydomain.com/my-page/de/roulette.html

They say they cannot crawl to this page.. but what kind of page is this ? what is /de there ?

I checked the link and my site says the page doesn't exist. Then i just noticed that my "Akismet" is not activated... So i will activate it now and how can i remove that extra link in my site?

Comment: You can request _any_ arbitrary URL from site, that doesn't mean that URL actually "exists", that's why they have "404 Error" responses. This likely a non-issue and unless you _actually_ have unwanted URLs in your site there is nothing to be done about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to activate Akismet. :)